# Receiving Run-Time Check Failure #2

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I would like to ask why am i getting Run-time Check Failure #2 When i am doing my program?
I'm very new to C programming.

I'm trying to make a Console application that have some option after they key in Y/N, 
But whenever i reach the end of all the option i get that error.

Could anyone tell me how i could solve it & what is the proper way of doing this kind of programming?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS // To allow Visual studio to use "scanf" function
#include <stdio.h> // Standard Input output . header
#include <Windows.h>

void codername() {
    printf("Coder: Rong Yuan\n");
}

void projectname() {
    printf("Project name: NPoly Learning\n");
}

void loadcurrentdate() {
    SYSTEMTIME str_t;
    GetSystemTime(&str_t);

    printf("Date: %d . %d . %d \n"
        , str_t.wDay, str_t.wMonth, str_t.wYear);
}

int main() {
    char option;
    int input;
    int mincome, fmember, total;

    printf("Do you like to see our option? Y/N \n");
    scanf("%s", &option);
    if (option == 'y' || option == 'Y') {
        printf("1. Display Coder Detail\n");
        printf("2. Display Project Name\n");
        printf("3. Load Current Date\n");
        printf("4. Calculator PCI\n");
        printf("5. Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &input);
    }
    else
        exit(1);

    switch (input) {
        case 1:
            codername();
            printf("Do you like to return to main?");
            break;

        case 2:
            projectname();
            break;

        case 3:
            loadcurrentdate();
            break;

        case 4:
            printf("Enter your house monthly income: ");
            scanf("%d", &mincome);
            printf("Enter total family member: (INCLUDING YOURSELF) ");
            scanf("%d", &fmember);
            total = mincome / fmember;
            printf("Total PCI: %d / %d = %d \n", mincome, fmember, total);
            system("pause");
            break;

        case 5:
            exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please copy the error message to your post ^^

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%s", &option);
```

is wrong as `option` is a `char` . So replace `%s` with `%c` there.`%s` should be used for strings (array of characters) and `%c` is the format specifier used for a character.